# How to convert time stamp with text into a date

Tags: excel

My data is extracting to this format May 22 2020 6:29PM

How do you convert this into 22/05/2020?

I have gotten the formula to this point =+LEFT(E12,LEN(E12) - FIND(" ",E12)-4) but cannot get it any further.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
=DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(E12,FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(E12," ","~",3)))," ",", ",2))
```

and apply the date format `dd/mm/yyyy` to the cell:

[image]

Note that this discards the time portion of the original date/time.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I seem to be struggling to get this to work though and it keeps returning #value!.  The issue seems to relate to datevalue not picking up "May"

Comment: What does just `SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(E12,FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(E12," ","~",3)))," ",", ",2)` return?

Comment: that returns May 25,2020

Comment: There should be a space after the comma: `May 25, 2020`. That's what the outer `SUBSTITUTE` does.